# Space complexity of statistic functions

Tags: space-complexity, statistics

When computing statistics on a list of data it occurred to me that most of the standard statistic functions, such as mean, min, max can be computed in *O(N)* time with *O(1)* space. They can also be computed incrementally, or "online", in *O(1)* space. That is, if the data were a stream we could compute the statistic without needing to store every previously seen item.

However, for computing the median *O(N)* space is required. There is no way to compute the median in a "rolling" fashion without maintaining all values in memory.

My question is, do these different classes of functions have a classification to describe them (beyond simply saying *O(1)* or *O(N)* space)? If I wanted to find more functions like median that require all elements to be present in memory to compute, what would I search for?

Comment: Note that there is an active research area - "data stream algorithms" - concerned with finding approximate answers to different statistic queries using highly sublinear space and time-per-item.

Comment: Mean/min/max really use logarithmic space, since you need that much space to store non-constant integers. Especially in the case of mean, even if the numbers are constant-size, you still need $O(\log n)$ bits to store the sum of $n$ constant-size numbers. I'd argue that $L$ (logspace) is the most natural complexity class for mean/min/max, but sadly it also contains the median problem (since it can be computed with $O(\log n)$ additional space and $O(n \log n)$ time. So you'd want to extend the definition of $L$ with a read-once constraint but that class hasn't been studied much (or at all).

Comment: @TomvanderZanden, thanks for the correction on *O(log N)* space for the mean/min/max. That makes sense. Can you elaborate on what you mean by an *O(log N)* additional space for the median though? If the computation needs all *N* numbers to compute the median and each number takes *log n* bits, wouldn't the total space be *O(N log N)*?

Also, why did you say *O(N log N)* time complexity? Can't the median could be computed in *O(N)* time using QuickSelect? Thanks for helping me understand.

Comment: Indeed, quickselect allows $O(n)$, I'm not sure how I came up with $O(n \log n)$. I said "additional space", so it gets to use (read-only) $O(n)$ (or $O(n \log n)$ if you want to be precise) space from which it can read the input, and $O(log n)$ (read/write) space to do the calculation. That ($O(log n)$ additional space) is the definition of $L$, which is why I suggested you need to extend the definition with some kind of read-once constraint. Mean/min/max also need $O(n \log n)$ space to store all the numbers, but they only read them once whereas quickselect may need to read them more often.

Comment: Also, another thought with regards to quickselect: if you only allow $O(log n)$ additional space, the $O(n)$ time bound may no longer apply (since this requires reordering the numbers). But you can definitely compute the median with $O(n^2)$ time and $O(\log n)$ additional space.

Comment: You may be interested in [our reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/844#844).

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the tips and pointers. I really appreciate it. @TomvanderZanden your comments, in particular, were super valuable.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden Why not turn your comments into an answer, so that we can get one unanswered question less?